# Cannot access hasMany models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Model **Joindraw.php**

```
class Joindraw extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'joindraw';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Model **User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function joindraw() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Joindraw');
}
```

**IndexController.php**

```
public function details(Request $request, $id, $fortune_code=null)
{
    $joindraw_participants = Joindraw::where('product_id', $id)->get();
}
```

**View.blade.php**

```
@forelse($joindraw_participants as $record)
    {{ $record->user->mobile }}
```

I'm getting error:

> getting property from non-object.

How can I access the child model from joindraw? and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your controller:

**IndexController.php**:

```
public function details(Request $request, $id, $fortune_code=null)
{
    $joindraw_participants = Joindraw::where('product_id', $id)->with('user')->get();
}
```

And In your blade, you can access user mobile like this:

```
{{ $joindraw_participants->user->mobile }}
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working and i was mistakenly had one row of ghost userid in joindraw table so getting the error earlier

Answer (score 0):

**Your controller :**

```
public function details(Request $request, $id, $fortune_code=null)
{
    $joindraw_participants = Joindraw::where('product_id', $id)->get();
}
```

**And your blade:**

```
@foreach($joindraw_participants as $record) 
  {{ $record->user->mobile }}
@endforeach
```